# Selenium c#: check page is scrolled to the top

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing my web application, and covering the "BackToTop" feature with infinitive scrolling. How can I understand using Selenium that page is scrolled up after "Back to top" button has been clicked?

I think, the most appropriate case is when Vertical Scroll bar is not shown, but cannot get this property from Window.

Comment: Get the position of an element when the page is not scrolled. Then to assert that the page is scrolled to the top, check again the same element position.

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong, but element location will be the same, despite window was scrolled or not.

Comment: I was referring to the position relative to the viewport: `.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;", element)`.

Comment: Thank Florent! You helped me a lot.